# Flattening a Single Table

Tags: sql

I am looking for a very basic flattening. I have a table in the database which provides each field for the employee in a different row.

```
EX 
  EMPLOYEE         GROUP_NAME
   81               BNEEO55
   81               BNELLIG
   81               LPKAPE
   81               HRFT
   90               BNRETINV
  ....
```

I would like to create a view which reports the data as:

```
EMPLOYEE     Group1      Group2        Group3         Group4         Group5
81           BNEEO55     BNELLIG       LPKAPE         HRFT           NULL
90           NULL        NULL          NULL           NULL           BNRETINV
```

OR

```
EMPLOYEE    BNEEO55     BNELLIG       LPKAPE         HRFT           BNRETINV
81          YES         YES           YES            YES            NO
90          NO          NO            NO             NO             YES
```

Comment: what type of database? also what are you trying to do? also, what do you mean by flatten?

Comment: I had wonderful spacing to show these all as charts, but that does not seem to come through. Sorry, I am new. If anyone can edit TIA

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server.  The table comes out with the employee number and one piece of data in the same column. This results in about 20 rows of data per employee. I would like it to flatten out to one row. with 20 some columns. One column for each type of data in the orignal column.

Comment: it's okay, Lacey :). what language are you planning on implementing your view in?

Comment: If you ask me, making the pivot table (that's what the last one is called by the way) is a presentation detail, it has nothing to do with your database or any queries. You retrieve normalized data from your DB and pass it to your presentation layer which handles displaying it in whatever format you need.

Comment: @Lacey - this is called a Pivot, and you can do it with SQL server, but only if you know the number of columns before hand (well, you can do it without knowing the number of columns, but that gets really messy).

Comment: I did not copy/paste. I tried to space it out when creating the posting to create a charted example. However, I must not understand how to get that spacing to appear in stack overflow since it just converted into a string. Any guidance?

Comment: There are 89 possibilities in the column right now, so once switch to columns there will be 90 (employee # column, plus the 89 possibilities).

Answer (score 4):

You need to PIVOT the data, if you are using SQL-Server 2008 or later you can use the PIVOT function:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Employee INT, Group_name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT #T VALUES (81, 'BNEEO55'), (81, 'BNELLIG'), (81, 'LPKAPE'), (81, 'HRFT'), (90, 'BNRETINV')

SELECT  Employee, 
        COALESCE([BNEEO55],'No') AS [BNEEO55],
        COALESCE([BNELLIG],'No') AS [BNELLIG],
        COALESCE([BNRETINV],'No') AS [BNRETINV],
        COALESCE([HRFT],'No') AS [HRFT],
        COALESCE([LPKAPE],'No') AS [LPKAPE]
FROM    (   SELECT  *, 'Yes' [Data]
            FROM    #T
        ) d
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(Data)
            FOR Group_Name IN ([BNEEO55], [BNELLIG], [BNRETINV], [HRFT], [LPKAPE])
        ) pvt
```

But it sounds like you need to do it dynamically if your data is changing. Something like the following would work:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ',' + QUOTENAME(Group_Name),
        @Cols = @Cols + ',COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(Group_Name) + ',''No'') AS ' + QUOTENAME(Group_Name)
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT Group_Name 
            FROM    #T
        ) T

SET @SQL = '
            SELECT  Employee, ' + STUFF(@Cols, 1, 1, '') + 
            'FROM   (   SELECT  *, ''Yes'' [Data]
                        FROM    #T
                    ) d
                    PIVOT
                    (   MAX(Data)
                        FOR Group_Name IN (' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 1, '') + ')
                    ) pvt'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

This builds up the same query as the first one, but means that when a new group name is added the query doesn't have to be altered.

---

**EDIT**

To create and call this as a stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE T (Employee INT, Group_name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT T VALUES (81, 'BNEEO55'), (81, 'BNELLIG'), (81, 'LPKAPE'), (81, 'HRFT'), (90, 'BNRETINV')
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE PivotT
AS

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ',' + QUOTENAME(Group_Name),
        @Cols = @Cols + ',COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(Group_Name) + ',''No'') AS ' + QUOTENAME(Group_Name)
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT Group_Name 
            FROM    T
        ) T

SET @SQL = '
            SELECT  Employee, ' + STUFF(@Cols, 1, 1, '') + 
            'FROM   (   SELECT  *, ''Yes'' [Data]
                        FROM    T
                    ) d
                    PIVOT
                    (   MAX(Data)
                        FOR Group_Name IN (' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 1, '') + ')
                    ) pvt'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
GO
EXECUTE PivotT
```

Comment: Yes, the dynamic is definately the way I will need to go. I am not fully understanding it though. I have not created a store procedure before. I assumed that I need to add the original table name somewhere so I added in place of #T and received the errors that it counld not find store procedure. Also, where in this am I pointing it to populate a view? Thanks.

Comment: What Version of SQL-Server are you using? You could not do this as a view, it would have to be a stored procedure. I've edited my answer to show how to create the procedure and call it. It may also be worth reading on MSDN about the [PIVOT Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). If you can post your schema on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0a0d/1) I can try and create an example more tailored to your needs.

Comment: I am using 2008. I see where PivotT is being created, but I not seeing where the SP_EXECUTESQL is being created. I am receiving message that it cannot find the stored procedure SP_EXECUTESQL.

Comment: I created some more data in SQL Fiddle and things worked wonderfully.